# $C^n$ for its projections implies $C^n$ for the map.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n$ be an integer. Suppose that we have two open intervals $I_1,I_2$ in $\mathbb R$ and a function $f:I_1\times I_2\to \mathbb R$ such that for each fixed $x\in I_1$ the map
$f(x,\cdot):I_2\to \mathbb R, y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is $C^n$ and for each fixed $y\in I_2$ the map
$f(\cdot,y):I_1\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is $C^n.$ Is it true that the map $f$ is $C^n?$ In the case $I_1=I_2,$ is it true that the map $x\mapsto f(x,x)$ is $C^n?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, $x,y\in(-1,1)$. Both $x\mapsto \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$
and $y\mapsto \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ are continuous as single variable functions (or have removable discontinuity), but what about continuity of $f$?